Disregard Carriage Return or Line Break when Importing CSV with Macro
I am trying to import a CSV into Excel using a macro but some of the CSV data contains what appears to be CR Carriage Returns or LB Line Breaks.  Instead of the CSV entry importing into the next one cell, it returns to the first column each time.
The CSV originates from an external application and in reviewing the file with Notepad, it appears they are carriage returns but I'm not certain.
If I use Excel's ribbon to manually import the CSV; Data > Get Data from Text/CSV > Import File > Load, it appears correctly and the CRs or LBs are disregarded.
If I use a macro, the CRs or LBs are applied and it returns to the first column for import and jumbles the format.
Sub ImportCSV()

flName = Application.GetOpenFilename("CSV files (*.csv),*.csv, All Files (*.*),*.*")

If flName = "False" Then Exit Sub

flName = "TEXT;" & flName

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=flName, Destination:=Range("A2"))
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .AdjustColumnWidth = False 
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells 
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False 
End With
 
End Sub

UPDATE: As per the comments, manual import works correctly so I recorded a macro using this method.  My problem still is that it's for a specific file and I'm not familiar enough with this coding to modify it to work for a variable file name.  If someone is able to assist, I'd greatly appreciate it.  This is the recorded macro -
 Sub InputCSV()
'
' InputCSV Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+t
'
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="ExampleFileCSV", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""D:\ExampleFileCSV.csv""),[Delimiter="","", Columns=17, Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.Csv])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Promoted Headers"",{{""Submission Date"", type date}, {""First Name"", type text}" & _
        ", {""Last Name"", type text}, {""Director/Tech ***Staff Only***"", type text}, {""Instrument/Colorguard"", type text}, {""Student Cell Phone Number"", type text}, {""Student Email "", type text}, {""Parent Email"", type text}, {""Monday, July 22nd (Whataburger)"", type text}, {""Tuesday, July 23 (Chick Fil A)"", type text}, {""Image Picker"", type text}, {""Thursday" & _
        ", July 25 (Marco's Pizza)"", type text}, {""Friday, July 26th (Smokey Mo's)"", type text}, {""Image Picker_1"", type text}, {""Saturday, July 27 (Marco's)"", type text}, {""Subtotal"", Int64.Type}, {""Total"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=ExampleFileCSV;Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [ExampleFileCSV]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "ExampleFileCSV"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Application.CommandBars("Queries and Connections").Visible = False
End Sub


I haven't tried converting a CSV file with CRs embedded in some fields using VBA, but as a work-around you could open the CSV file and globally replace (only the embedded) CRs with some other unused character (such as "|"). Then perform the CVS import. When the import is complete, globally replace the placeholder character with the original CR.

The old Legacy wizard produces a similar code (there is a newer wizard that uses PowerQuery). Try to record a macro for the manual import that worked for you. Then compare the recorded code with the one you posted. You might have more relevant properties set in the recorded code e.g. .TextFilePlatform (not sure about its relevance).

I recorded a macro of the manual input.  What is different is the way it opens the file name but not sure how to post in this comments section as it's too long.  Will try in sections:

1/2)ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="ExampleFileCSV", Formula:= _
"let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""D:\ExampleFileCSV.csv""),[Delimiter="","", Columns=17, Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.Csv])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Promoted Headers"",{{""Submission Date"", type date},[lists headers]& Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""

2/2)ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
"OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=ExampleFileCSV;Extended Properties=""""" _
, Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable

Chr(13) is for Carriage Return and Chr(10) is for New Line and must be the reason the manual way works but I don't know how to incorporate it into the code I have since the manual version of the macro is specific to this file.

You should copy the code you're showing to your post. The code is produced using the new wizard that uses PowerQuery. Why wouldn't you use it? You can try to record the operation using the Legacy wizard and then compare the codes. Maybe it will work since I told you before that some properties are missing in your code. Use Data->Get Data->Legacy Wizards->From Text (Legacy). While recording, play with the various properties (options) and see how the code changes.

I did try cutting + pasting the code but it doesn't work.  It's file specific when I need it variable and I don't understand the coding in order to properly change it.

Better to edit your question than post hard to parse code in comments.

I edited the question above to include this code and my issue.
